# Android: find a file created in AVD

Tags: android, file, android-virtual-device, internal-storage

My application has a function of creating an xls file. After that I need to access that file manually. Now, the problem is, when i run the app on my device, I am able to locate the directories and my xls file in internal storage.

But when I try to run that in the AVD, I am not able to find the file. I also viewed `file explorer` but there also, I wasn't able to find my file.

Where does the file exists when created in AVD?
Below is the code :

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PB/automation/mydir/");
myFolder.mkdirs();
File file = new File(myFolder, "demo.xls");
```

Trust me, there is nothing wrong with the code.
Below is the `file explorer` view :
[image]

Comment: Check inside `mnt` option.

Comment: nope. Nothing there as well.

Comment: Do you give to application in Android Manifest write and read to external storage permisions. also try to check inside data/yourapplicationnSignature/folders

Comment: Yes I do have that entry in Manifest. As i said, the app successfully creates the file when i try it on my physical device.